# Why has only the Cauchy Residue Theorem used for one of the solutions whilst both contour integration and CRT used in the other?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-transform, cauchy-integral-formula

In the solutions to the following answers only CRT has been used for B7 whilst both CRT and contour integration has been used for B6. The question is the same so I am unsure why the solutions have a varying method to find k(x,y). I suspect it might have to do with the hints given at the bottom of each question but even then for B6 it gives that hint but also requires CRT to be used since the hint would be useful for contour integration only.

[image]

[image]

Comment: At first the residue theorem is just a corollary of the Cauchy integral theorem and formula (not complicated to prove for analytic functions). More generally, it means evaluating an integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ as $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\gamma_n} f(z)dz$ with $f$ complex analytic, $\gamma_n$ a sequence of closed contours, so $\int_{\gamma_n} f(z)dz$ is evaluated using the residue theorem.

Comment: so why have no closed contours been used in the evaluation of B7 ?

Comment: I just said residue theorem and contour integration is **the same THING**. If you don't see closed contours here it is because you didn't understand well.

Comment: I know they are the same thing but generally in these sort of questions both CRT and contour integration is used then the answers are equated to get k(x,y) but b7's solution is different so I am wondering if there is something I am missing

Comment: in fact I did use closed contours in my answer but in the solution it isn't used I guess it is missing content in that case

Comment: Once you know a little bit of complex analysis you are allowed to write $$2i\pi\sum_{P(\alpha)=0,\Im(\alpha) > 0} Res(\frac{e^{2i \pi \xi z} }{P(z)},\alpha)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty+\int_{\infty}^{i\infty}+\int_{i\infty}^{-\infty} \frac{e^{2i \pi \xi z} }{P(z)}dz = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{2i \pi \xi z} }{P(z)}dz$$ for any polynomial $P$ without real roots and $\Re(\xi) > 0$.

Comment: That helps many thanks

Comment: @reuns: How about you post your comment as an answer, since the asker says it helped?